# '/' home nav item color is showing active even changing of NavLink in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I'm using NavLink to show the for Routing and showing item active of selected items.By default the home item is showing as active even I switched to other item. Except home others are working as expected.

Help me to sort out this bug.

In the following figure, Home (in red color) as active color even I switched to contact

[image]

My code as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

class TopNav extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-bg">
          {/* <img className="logo-image" src={logo} alt="logo" /> */} Logo
          <button
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <NavLink
                  className="nav-link menu-list "
                  activeClassName="active"
                  to="/"
                >
                  Home
                </NavLink>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item ">
                <NavLink
                  className="nav-link menu-list"
                  activeClassName="active"
                  to="about"
                >
                  About
                </NavLink>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <NavLink className="nav-link menu-list"  activeClassName="active" to="contact">
                  Contact
                </NavLink>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(TopNav);
```

Comment: add the exact attribute to the NavLink for "/". [Documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/exact-bool)

Comment: Add the [exact](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/exact-bool) attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also specify the [exact](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/exact-bool) prop on `NavLink` components. The `to` prop (*and `path` prop for `Route` components*) match by path prefix, and "/" is a prefix for all routes.

> **exact: bool**
>
> When true, the active class/style will only be applied if
> the location is matched exactly.

```
<NavLink
  className="nav-link menu-list "
  activeClassName="active"
  to="/"
  exact // <-- specify exact match!
>
  Home
</NavLink>
```